# Constant of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

> Consider the integral  $$\int x \arctan (x) \;dx$$ Evaluate this integral using integration by parts. Then find a constant of integration that makes the last integration trivial. Compare the answers and explain any differences.

I know how to integrate by parts, I got $$\frac{x^2 \arctan (x) + \arctan (x) - x}{2} + C$$ but I don’t get the part where it asks to a find a constant of integration that makes the last trivial.

If somebody could please explain?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the source of this problem

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration) is a source that is tedious to read but perhaps helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int x \arctan (x) \;dx
&=
\int \frac 12(x^2+1)' \arctan (x) \;dx
\\
&=
\frac 12(x^2+1)\arctan (x)
-
\int \frac 12(x^2+1) \arctan' (x) \;dx
\\
&=
\frac 12(x^2+1)\arctan (x)
-
\int \frac 12(x^2+1) \cdot\frac 1{x^2+1} \;dx
\\
&=
\frac 12(x^2+1)\arctan (x)
-
\int \frac 12\;dx
\\
&=
\frac 12(x^2+1)\arctan (x)
-
\frac x2
+\text{(locally) constant .}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int x\arctan x\,dx=\left(\frac{x^2}2+C\right)\arctan x-\frac12\int\frac{x^2+2C}{x^2+1}dx.$$

Indeed, the choice $C=\dfrac12$ is advantageous.